# GLSL - Set color of vertex

Tags: opengl, glsl

I want to darken the corners of my little quad in my program. I have the following vertex shader:

```
#version 130

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    v_color = gl_Color.rgba;
    v_texcoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
    gl_FrontColor = vec4(v_color.r, v_color.g, v_color.b, 1.0f);
    gl_Position = ftransform(); 
}
```

And my fragment shader:

```
#version 130

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
```

I read somewhere that `gl_FrontColor` could be used to "color" vertices, but no matter what I change the values to, it always seems to stay the same.

My question is, what function can I use to set the color of my vertices? I want the vertices to be slightly darker than the rest of the quad so it looks a little "nicer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You output to both `v_color` (your varying), and `gl_FrontColor` (GLSL builtin). But, in fragment shader, you only use `v_color`, so anything that is in `gl_FrontColor` is being ignored.

You should use only one of these. Either

```
// vertex
#version 130

#define SCALE_FACTOR 0.5

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    v_color = vec4(gl_Color.rgb * SCALE_FACTOR, 1.0);
    v_texcoord = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
    gl_Position = ftransform(); 
}

// fragment
#version 130

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texcoord;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = v_color * texture2D(u_texture, v_texcoord);
}
```

Or use `gl_FrontColor` in vertex and `gl_Color` in fragment shader, instead of your `v_color` (and remove this varying as it no longer needed).

Of course vertex `gl_Color` attribute comes from `glColorPointer`, - if you changed that colors, it would be changed in shader too.

Comment: So what would gl_Color look like in the fragment shader?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. `gl_Color` have different meaning in different places. In vertex shader, it is attribute that comes from `glColorPointer`. In fragment shader, it is varying taken either from `gl_FrontColor` or `gl_BackColor` (interpolated between vertices), depending on polygon orientation. So, basically, you could just use it instead of your `v_color` in fragment shader, and remove `v_color` completely.